# Present participle to join sentences

Tags: grammar, participle-clauses

Here are two sentences which have been transformed into two different kinds of sentence having a different structure to the first version:

> 1a) All the employees are huge basketball fans. That makes it a very fun winter.
>   1b) He couldn’t give me a straight answer. This leaves a lot of room for doubt.
>
> 2a) All the employees are huge basketball fans, making it a very fun winter.
>   2b) He couldn’t give me a straight answer, leaving a lot of room for doubt.

Source: http://www.writeexpress.com/emphasis.html

I think it's the use of present participle(ing form) connecting two different sentences into one sentence. Isn't it? Do we use such sentences to show the result of first clause to the second clause ? Or why we use such sentences ?

I think we use such sentences to emphasize our writing(as per the website content refers to), But I don't know what kind of emphasize it is.

Comment: It makes for a more flowing kind of writing, but hardly emphasizes anything.

Answer (score 1):

From your linked website:

> Relative clauses can also be used to add subordinate information.

The two examples are of *additional* information, meaning that it would be fine to leave out this information, even if it is interesting.  Linking with the present participle gives no more or less emphasis than using other kinds of linking.

> I plan to go to the doctor tomorrow, making it the first time in a while I've been.
>
> I plan to go to the doctor tomorrow, where I hope I get a clean checkup.
>
> I plan to go to the doctor tomorrow, if I can get there with all the traffic.

With all of these, the second part is subordinate information, but all are of (more or less) equal emphasis.  You can even put two (or more) in the same sentence:

> I plan to go to the doctor tomorrow, making it the first time in a while I've been -- if I can get there with all the traffic.